# HoloEverywhere - conflict attributes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-holo-everywhere

I added maven repository of HoloEverywhere and added dependence on library.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://192.241.191.41/repo" }
    }
}
```

Just set the patch to the library.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'org.holoeverywhere:library:+@aar'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

When I try to run the apllication getting there errors

```
/home/onea/projects/java/android/TestApp/app/build/exploded-aar/com.android.support/appcompat-v7/19.0.1/res/values/values.xml
Error:Attribute "spinnerMode" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "popupPromptView" has already been defined
Error:Attribute "disableChildrenWhenDisabled" has already been defined
```

What am I doing wrong? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced line in dependencies

```
compile 'org.holoeverywhere:library:+@aar'
```

to

```
compile 'org.holoeverywhere:library:+'
```

becose compilator shows errors in holoeverywhere activity and remove

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```